# Print filenames containing multiple strings

Tags: grep, find

Let's say I have multiple files with `.ext` extension containing multiple lines. I need to print filenames containing all 3 keywords: `kwd1`, `kwd2`, and `kwd3`.

How do I do it?

Comment: Are you at all interested in the content of the files, or do you just want to match the keywords against the filenames?  Saying "I want to print the filenames containing the keywords" implies that you are only interested in the filenames.

Comment: Is it the filename or the file content that is multi-line? Please improve question, as it is currently hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find all filenames ending in `.ext` and containing the three keywords `kwd1`, `kwd2` and `kwd3`, anywhere in or below the current directory:

```
find . -name '*.ext' -name '*kwd1*' -name '*kwd2*' -name '*kwd3*'
```

Or, setting the keywords in a more dynamic way,

```
set -- "kwd1" "kwd2" "kwd3"

for word do
    set -- "$@" -name "*$word*"
    shift
done

find . -name "*.ext" "$@" -print
```

Or, if you want to search for the keywords inside the files:

```
set -- "kwd1" "kwd2" "kwd3"

for word do
    set -- "$@" -exec grep -q -wF -e "$word" {} ';'
    shift
done

find . -name "*.ext" "$@" -print
```

I'm using `-wF` with `grep` here to only do a string comparison (`-F`) of whole words (`-w`) in the files.

In a shell supporting named arrays, that last bit of code might look like

```
keywords=( "kwd1" "kwd2" "kwd3" )

and_expr=()
for word in "${keywords[@]}"; do
    and_expr+=( -exec grep -q -wF -e "$word" {} ';' )
done

find . -name "*.ext" "${and_expr[@]}" -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext" -exec grep -q kwd1 {} \; -exec grep -q kwd2 {} \; -exec grep -l kwd3 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive grep and read:

```
grep --include '*.ext' -lr 'kwd1' . | 
while read -r file; do grep -m1 -q 'kwd2' "$file" && grep -m1 -l 'kwd3' "$file"; done
```

`grep --include '*.ext' -lr 'kwd1' .` - Will find all files (recursively) in the current directory that end in `.ext` and contain `kwd1`

The while loop will then take each file containing `kwd1` and confirm that it also has both `kwd2` and `kwd3`

Note: This will break on filenames containing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `find` command to identify all the target files and then run a `grep` on those to detect the files.

```
$ find . -name '*.ext' -type f -exec grep -Pqz '(?s:(?=.*kwd1.*)(?=.*kwd2.*)(?=.*kwd3.*))' \{\} \; -print
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested with below method and it worked fine:

```
for i in file file2...filen; do grep "kwd1" $i; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then grep "kwd2" $i; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then grep "kwd3" $i; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then echo "file is $i"; fi; fi; fi; done
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this is doing, we generally prefer longer form answers on this site. Code with no explanation is nice but answers with more specifics are best.

Comment: it will print all filenames which consists of above mentioned 3 strings. it will check for first string then proceed for second string then 3rd string